# specific cell weight in grid layout

Tags: android

I have read about columnWeight and rowWeight and how it can used to define the size of the cells automatically on the basis of ratios.

Since i am new , i tried making a calculator app.

[image]

This is what i achieved through my learning.

[image]

This is what i was hoping for my app to be .

I cant seem to extend my `ok` button to the whole yellow shaded area.

how would i achieve this one?

**Code**

```
 <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_grid_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:columnCount="4"

            android:rowCount="5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:useDefaultMargins="false"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:rowOrderPreserved="false"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="ac"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="c"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="116dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="289dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="/"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="129dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="255dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="0"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="7"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="64dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="259dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="2"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="9"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="129dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="217dp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="0"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="2"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="6" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="0"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="1" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="2"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="3" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="0"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="%" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button21"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button22"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_column="2"

                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="." />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:text="x"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="129dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="168dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:text="-"

                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="41dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="180dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="3"

                android:text="+" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button19"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"

                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="3"

                android:text="OK" />

        </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `android:layout_rowSpan="2"`in your ok button

Comment: You are a God.Can you explain me , how row spans work?

Comment: What's a span , i meant?

Comment: row span means expanding height of button in the given number of rows or value. For example :- In the above picture there are 5 rows so the row span is 2 ,that is the button height will occupy the height of 2 rows.  In simple term They provide the same functionality as “merge cell” in spreadsheet programs like Excel.